# overlapping GridView and Canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `Canvas` and a `GridView` to which I am adding multiple `Rectangle` and `Images`. What I want is to Rectangles and images to overlap and appear as one.

I have written almost the same code for Rectangles and Images but for some reason I am not getting them together.

Here is the code :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {

                rect = new Rectangle();

                rect.Height = canvas1.Height / 8;
                rect.Width = canvas1.Width / 8;

                th = new Thickness((i * canvas1.Height / 8) + 10, (j * canvas1.Width / 8) + 10, 0, 0);
                rect.Margin = th;

                rect.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                canvas1.Children.Add(rect);
             }
         }
```

and similar is the code for Image but with Grid instead of canvas1. What changes should I do to make the image overlap to the rectangle?

Comment: Why not put a Rectangle and the overlayed Image into the same Grid cell, i.e. use the same `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` values for both. No need for an additional Canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perhaps define a Grid with 8 rows and columns, and then set row and column indices for your rectangles and images:

```
<Grid Name="grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Fill="Red"/>
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="image00" />
    ... more rectangles and images ...
</Grid>
```

You may optionally set the `Width` of each ColumnDefinition and the `Height` of each RowDefinition.

If you need to dynamically add the controls to the Grid, you could do this:

```
Image image = ...
int column = ...
int row = ...
Grid.SetColumn(image, column);
Grid.SetRow(image, row);
grid.Children.Add(image);
```

---

Also, for your information, Canvas provides the [Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.left%28v=vs.100%29), [Top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.top%28v=vs.100%29), [Right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.right%28v=vs.100%29) and [Bottom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.bottom%28v=vs.100%29) properties for arranging its children. Instead of setting Margins as you do in your code, you would typically set `Left` and `Top`:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(child, left);
Canvas.SetTop(child, top);
```